# Find the distance travelled in 1st second given the following conditions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> A person travels a distance AB of $15.625$m in $5$ seconds.In the last $4$ seconds,every second he covers a distance equal to $1$/$4$ of the total distance covered. upto the end of the previous second.Find the distance travelled in 1st second?

options:

a)$6.4$ b)$3.125$ c)$2.5$ d)$5$

MyApproach:

d=$15.625$

t=$5$sec

speed=$15.625$/$5$=$3.125$ m/s

So,Distance travelled in 1st second=3.125m

> Am i right in my approach?Please correct me if I am wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the *average* distance travelled in each second, but he is obviously not moving at at constant speed, so it is not likely to be his speed in any particular second.

To solve this problem, you need to convert the information given into a mathematical formulation:

Let $d$ be the distance travelled in the first second (so the final answer you want is the value of $d$).

(Edited to correct an error in step 3, and make it a little easier.)

Note that if $D$ is the total distance travelled at the start of the second, then you travel an additional $\frac D 4$, for a new total of $D + \frac D 4 = \frac 5 4 D$

1. Total distance travelled in the first one second is $d$.
2. Total distance travelled is $\frac 5 4 d$
3. Total distance travelled is $\frac 5 4 \left(\frac 5 4 d\right) = \left(\frac 5 4 \right)^2d$.
4. Total distance travelled is $\frac 5 4 \left(\frac 5 4 \right)^2d = \left(\frac 5 4 \right)^3d$.
5. Total distance travelled is $\frac 5 4 \left(\frac 5 4 \right)^3d = \left(\frac 5 4 \right)^4d$.

So the equation you need to solve is $$\left(\frac 5 4 \right)^4d = 15.625.$$

So $d=6.4$. The person travels 6.4 meters in the first second.

Comment: @Pauk Sinclair Sir,I got $341$d/$256$=15.625 =>d=11.I am not getting correct Ans?Am I doing wrong somewhere?

Comment: The mistake was *mine*. I went a little too quickly in step 3, and put in the wrong number. It is not $d$ that you add to $\frac{5d}{16}$, but the distance previously travelled, which was $\frac{5d}{4}$, so the correct value is as seen in the edit above